# how to remove everything except {Group} and {Desc} from string variable cardLabel and add a space between them in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I get cardLabel value from database and the value sometimes contain all 6 variables but can contain value with sometimes just 2 variables, sometimes with sometimes just 4 variables. Please note order for the variables can be different and can contain more variables in future.

cardLabel’s dynamic value examples:

```
cardLabel='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles {DeductibleAmount} {DeductibleType}';

cardLabel='{Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles';

cardLabel='{Desc} {Group} - {termMonth} Month';

cardLabel='{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month {DeductibleAmount}';
```

I have tried the following code but it is not ideal because the database value can contain more variables in future:

```js
cardLabel =  cardLabel.replace('{termMonth}','').replace('{termOdometer}','').replace('{DeductibleAmount}','').replace('{DeductibleType}','').replace('-', '');
```

The desire end result should be one of the following:
cardLabel='{Group} {Desc}';
cardLabel='{Desc} {Group}';

Comment: (1) Please add the desired result for your sample strings to your question. (2) Are you familiar with `Regular Expressions`?

Comment: The desire end result should be one of the following:
cardLabel='{Group} {Desc}';
cardLabel='{Desc} {Group}';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if this is what you need. It uses simple Regular Expression.

Such expression can be built dynamically if so required.

```js
cardLabels=[
'{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles {DeductibleAmount} {DeductibleType}', 
'{Desc} - {termMonth} Month - {termOdometer} KMs/Miles', 
'{Desc} {Group} - {termMonth} Month',
'{Group} {Desc} - {termMonth} Month {DeductibleAmount}'
]

cardLabels.forEach(label=>console.log(GroupDesk(label)));

function GroupDesk(lbl) {
  regex=/({Desc}|{Group})+/g;
  return lbl.match(new RegExp(regex)).join(" ");
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for all your help.